# Code Coverage is showing constant value as 52% its not getting increased

Tags: unit-test

Based on the requirement i need to change a line code in the trigger and written a test class which has above 75%.When i deployed the trigger and test class the system was throwing an error as

```
Code Coverage Error .Trigger should have atleast 1%.
```

When i run all test in production its showing as 70% .Their are few triggers and classes where their are no test classes for few.I'm writing a test class for one of the trigger where the same line code is throwing an error for other triggers and test classes.

```
   OrgWideEmailAddress[] owea1 = [select Id from OrgWideEmailAddress where Address = 'customercare@cleanse.com'];
```

The test class code is constantly showing as 52% whether i increase the line code or decrease the line.

Test class :

```
@isTest
public class TestthankYouNoteMail
{
    static testMethod void testthank1()
    {
        Account acc2 = new Account(Name='Testing SubscriptionClone', BillingStreet='Banjara hills', BillingCity='Hyd', BillingState='TS',
                                    BillingPostalCode = '500084', BillingCountry = 'India', Phone = '100', Industry = 'Banking',
                                    Type = 'Paid', Customer_Type__c = 'Customer', Customer_List__c = true);
        insert acc2 ;
        contact cc2 = new contact(FirstName ='Test Contact Subscription', LastName ='Opptyclone', Role__c='Subscription Administrator',AccountId=acc2.Id);
        insert cc2;

        Opportunity opty2 = new Opportunity(Name = 'Test SubscriptionOppty', StageName ='Proposal/Price Quote', Probability =60, 
                                            CloseDate = System.Today(), Type = 'Existing Customer', Assigned_Sales_Engineer__c = null, 
                                            Update_Complete__c = true, Partner__c = 'None', Anchor__c='Non Anchor', AccountId = acc2.Id,
                                            Payment_Type__c = 'Order Form', LeadSource = 'Subscription Renewal');
        insert opty2;

        list<OpportunityContactRole> opptyConRolelist2 =  new list<OpportunityContactRole>{
            new OpportunityContactRole(ContactId = cc2.Id, OpportunityId = opty2.Id, IsPrimary = false, Role = 'Subscription Administrator')
        };   
        insert opptyConRolelist2;

        opty2.StageName ='Closed won';

        //Test.Starttest();
        update opty2;
        // Test.Stoptest();

        //// Custom Setting for template
        String EmailtemplateThankYouNote; 
        String EmailCommunicationtemplate;

        ThankYounote__c thankyou1 = ThankYounote__c.getInstance();
        EmailtemplateThankYouNote = thankyou1.Template_Id__c;    
        EmailCommunicationtemplate  = thankyou1.Communication_Template__c;

        boolean Condition1=false;
        boolean Condition2=false;

        OrgWideEmailAddress[] owea1 = [select Id from OrgWideEmailAddress where Address = 'customercare@cleanse.com'];

        String addresses = '';
        String[] toAddresses;
        String targetid;

        string templateIdToUse;
        Condition1 = opty2.ThankYou_Note__c;
        Condition2 = opty2.CustomerCare__c;

        OpportunityContactRole ocrole = new OpportunityContactRole();
        if(Condition1 || Condition2)
        {
            if(ocrole.contact.Email!=null)
            {
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                email.setUseSignature(false);
                email.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
                email.setTemplateID(EmailtemplateThankYouNote);
                email.setTargetObjectId(targetid);
            }
            else
            {
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                email.setUseSignature(false);
                email.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
                email.setTemplateID(EmailCommunicationtemplate);
                email.setTargetObjectId(targetid);    
            }
        }
```

Trigger :

```
trigger thankYouNoteMail on Opportunity (after update)
{
    Set<id> oid = new Set<id>();
    List<OpportunityContactRole> ocrList = new List<OpportunityContactRole>();

    for(Opportunity o : Trigger.new)
    {
        oid.add(o.id);
    }

    if(oid.size() > 0)
    {
        ocrList = [Select Role,OpportunityId,ContactId,Contact.Email From OpportunityContactRole Where OpportunityId In : oid AND Role = 'Subscription Administrator'];
    }

    //// Custom Setting for template
    String EmailtemplateThankYouNote; 
    String EmailCommunicationtemplate;

    ThankYounote__c thankyou = ThankYounote__c.getInstance();
    EmailtemplateThankYouNote = thankyou.Template_Id__c;    
    EmailCommunicationtemplate  = thankyou.Communication_Template__c; 

    Map<String,List<OpportunityContactRole>> idOCRMap = new Map<String,List<OpportunityContactRole>>();        
    List<OpportunityContactRole> templist;

    if(ocrList.size() > 0)
    {
        for(OpportunityContactRole ba : ocrList)
        {       
            if(!idOCRMap.containskey(ba.opportunityId))
            {
                tempList = new List<OpportunityContactRole>();
            }   
            else
            {
                tempList = idOCRMap.get(ba.opportunityId);
            }
            tempList.add(ba);
            idOCRMap.put(ba.opportunityId,tempList);
        }
    }

    OrgWideEmailAddress[] owea = [select Id from OrgWideEmailAddress where Address = 'customercare@cleanse.com'];

     string templateIdToUse;
     boolean cond1 = false;
     boolean cond2 = false;
    for(Opportunity opp : trigger.new)
    {
        String addresses = '';
        String[] toAddresses;
        String targetid;

        cond1 = opp.ThankYou_Note__c && (trigger.isupdate && opp.ThankYou_Note__c != trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).ThankYou_Note__c);
        cond2 = opp.CustomerCare__c && (trigger.isupdate && opp.CustomerCare__c != trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).CustomerCare__c);
        if(cond1 || cond2)
        {
            if(idOCRMap.containskey(opp.id))
            {
                for(OpportunityContactRole ocr : idOCRMap.get(opp.id))
                {
                    if(ocr.Contact.Email != null)
                    {
                        addresses += ocr.Contact.Email + ':';
                    }
                    toAddresses = addresses.split(':', 0);
                    targetid = ocr.ContactId;
                    system.debug('toAddresses:::::::::::::::::::::::::'+toAddresses);
                } 
                if(cond1)
                {
                    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                    if (owea.size() > 0 ) 
                    {
                        mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owea.get(0).Id);
                    }

                    mail.setUseSignature(false);
                    mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
                    mail.setTemplateID(EmailtemplateThankYouNote);
                    mail.setTargetObjectId(targetid);
                    try
                    {
                        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail });
                        system.debug('mail***************************'+mail);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        system.debug('Exception:::::::::::'+e);
                    }
                }
                if(cond2)
                {
                    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                    if (owea.size() > 0 ) 
                    {
                        mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owea.get(0).Id);
                    }

                    mail.setUseSignature(false);
                    mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
                    mail.setTemplateID(EmailCommunicationtemplate);
                    mail.setTargetObjectId(targetid);
                    try
                    {
                        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail });
                        system.debug('mail***************************'+mail);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        system.debug('Exception:::::::::::'+e);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: Try running test from Apex class in Setup -> Apex Class -> Run test

Comment: @karthikselva:Thanks for your response.when i run test from Apex Test Execution or In Developer Console i get the constant test code coverage as 52%.Or else is the test class written is wrong.Any suggestion plz.

Comment: What is the error you are getting when you are running the test. If your test class errors out then most likely its not going to cover much of code and hence not much difference in overall code coverage.

Comment: @Prady:I dont get any error.when i run the test class ,it gets passed but the code coverage remains the same .I think i got stucked with the  IF conditions and email message which are not getting covered.Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: I saw in your post you were mentioning about an error. For the if condition you would need to build your test data such a way that you will navigate through the if and else conditions. For ex if you have written a trigger on Opportunity and if you are checking if the opp is closed/won you do someting and in the else you do something else. Your test data should be such that 1 record would have the stage as closed/won and another set of opps with someother stage. That way both the scenarios are covered. Ideally i would have two test methods doing these tests. one for stageWon and other for other

Comment: @Prady:Thanks for the response.Before writing the test class for this trigger.When i run all test classes at that time for two - three triggers it started throwing the same error as : OrgWideEmailAddress[] owea1 = [select Id from OrgWideEmailAddress where Address = 'customercare@cleanse.com'];.Then i started writing the test class for this particular trigger.But still no luck..getting stucked.

Comment: You probably need to post the trigger code as well. Btw what are you trying to do in the test class?

Comment: @Prady:I have posted the trigger code.Any suggestion plz

Comment: Ok.. In the opp that you are updating, have the ThankYou_Note__c and CustomerCare__c as true. this should cover the code in the if conditions

Comment: try to run all classses and solve all classes with error.

Comment: All the lines after the `Test.stoptest()` in your testmethod make no sense. The code being tested (after update trigger) generates the email, the testmethod shouldn't replicate all that setup/sending.

Comment: @Prady:Thanks for your reply.The code coverage got increased to 96% by updating those two fields values..

Comment: Glad i could be of help. But as mentioned by @crop1645 the lines after `Test.stoptest() doesnt make sense. All of those should be on the trigger and not the test class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the opp that you are updating, have the `ThankYou_Note__c` and `CustomerCare__c` as true. this should cover the code in the if conditions.

Right now the execution is not getting into those branches of if statements because the conditions are not fulfilled.